# Javascript find recursively in JSON object

Tags: javascript, json

I have the following array:

```
c = ['foo', 'bar'];
```

and an object

```
this.foobar = {"foo":{"bar":123}};
```

How can I search for each of the elements in the array in the JSON object that I have. It needs to be recursive. A PHP version with arrays of what I am trying to do would be something along the lines of:

```
function in_array_recursive($needle, $haystack) { 
    if(in_array($needle, $haystack)) 
        return true; 
    foreach($haystack as $elem) 
        if(is_array($elem) && in_array_recursive($needle, $elem) 
            return true; 
    return false; 
}
```

However what I need to do is the same but in JavaScript and instead of arrays I need to use JSON.

Comment: Is the JSON only an array of elements(or of array of elements, and so on)? Or is it an object? If it's an object you need to tell us more informations, maybe providing some examples of what you want to be achieved(do you need key or value-based search?)

Comment: Do you need true/false or do you want the value returned? Or the key? In a recursive context the key might take the form of an array of keys. Are you looking for one value, or multiple values? Maybe it'd help if you explained a bit about the problem you were trying to solve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something like the below, which looks for keys that match needle

```
var foobar = {
    "foo": {
        "whooop" : {
        "bar" : 123
        }
    }
};

function isInArray(needle, haystack) { 
    var foundNeedle = false;

    for (var key in haystack) {

        if (isInArray(needle, haystack[key])) {
            foundNeedle = true;
        }

        if (key == needle) {
            foundNeedle = true
        }
    }

    return foundNeedle;    
}  

var message = "is bar in foobar? result is... " +  isInArray("bar", foobar));
```

Comment: Note that @Steven is using this as an example of how to recurse in Javascript, rather than giving you the code you need. You'll need to do some tweaking before applying this to generic JSON objects. For example running the code above against an object that contained string values, e.g. `isInArray("bar", {foo:"bar"})` would result in infinite recursion (because you can loop over strings) and blow the call stack.

Comment: Good point, you'd have to guard against that with something like `     if (typeof haystack[key] == "object") {
            if (isInArray(needle, haystack[key])) {
                foundNeedle = true;
            }
        }
`  also since I'm assuming that you're only wanting to check for matching keys, not for matching values `isInArray("bar", {foo:"bar"})` would return false.